# What is the fastest algorithm to establish whether a linear system in $\mathbb{R}$ has a solution?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, linear-algebra

I know the best algorithm to solve a linear system in $\mathbb{R}$ with $n$ variables is Coppersmith-Winograd's algorithm, which has a complexity of
$$
O\left(n^{2.376}\right).
$$
How much easier is it to simply determine whether the same system has any solution?

More precisely, given a system of $m$ equations and $n$ unknowns, what is the complexity of establishing whether it has any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether or not Coppersmith-Winograd is the "best" algorithm depends on your circumstances, of course. CW and algorithms like it are usually considered impractical due to high constant factors. [Strassen's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm) is more common in practice.

But since computational complexity is what you are interested in, CW was beaten quite recently.

- Virginia Vassilevska Williams (2014), [Multiplying matrices in $O(n^{2.373})$ time](http://theory.stanford.edu/~virgi/matrixmult-f.pdf), Stanford University.

As far as we know, calculating the determinant of a matrix, or eigenvalue estimation, or anything else that could be used to determine if a matrix is singular or not are at least as complex as matrix multiplication.

Comment: Does "As far as we know" mean that someone has given a reduction from matrix multiplication to determining whether it has a solution?  Or is it just a commonly held "feeling"?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm also curious about what @j_random_hacker asked. Is there any reference for this claim?

Comment: Yes. See Bunch & Hopcroft, "Triangular Factorization and Inversion by Fast Matrix Multiplication". https://apps.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/754790.pdf

Essentially, if two matrices of order $n$ can be multiplied in $M(n) = \Omega(n^2)$ time, then triangular factorisation, inversion, and determinant calculation can be performed in $O(M(n))$ time.